# JOLT transform flatten nested array with key value pairs

Tags: json, jolt

I'm trying to transform the following JSON

```
{
  "data": {
    "keyvalues": [
      {
        "key": "location",
        "value": "sydney, au"
      },
      {
        "key": "weather",
        "value": "sunny"
      }
    ]
  },
  "food": {
    "name": "AllFoods",
    "date": "2018-03-08T09:35:17-03:00",
    "count": 2,
    "food": [
      {
        "name": "chocolate",
        "date": "2018-03-08T12:59:58-03:00",
        "rating": "10",
        "data": null
      },
      {
        "name": "hot dog",
        "date": "2018-03-08T09:35:17-03:00",
        "rating": "7",
        "data": {
          "keyvalues": [
            {
              "key": "topping",
              "value": "mustard"
            },
            {
              "key": "BUN type",
              "value": "toasted"
            },
            {
              "key": "servings",
              "value": "2"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Into, something simpler like this, using JOLT (in NIFI).  Bringing the first top-level `food` attributes (`name`, `date`, `count`) into the `header` and then pulling the nested `food` array up, and then flattening out the `food.data.keyvalues` into a dict/hashmap.

```
{
  "header": {
    "location": "sydney, au",
    "weather": "sunny",
    "date": "2018-03-08",
    "count": 2
  },
  "foods": [
    {
      "name": "chocolate",
      "date": "2018-03-08T12:59:58-03:00",
      "rating": "10"
    },
    {
      "name": "hot dog",
      "date": "2018-03-08T09:35:17-03:00",
      "rating": "7",
      "topping": "mustard",
      "bun_type": "toasted",
      "servings": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've got the first `data` part working, but I'm not sure how to handle the nested `food` element.  The top level `food` info needs to move into the `header` section, and the second level `food` array, needs to flatten out the `data.keyvalues`.

Current spec... (only handles the top `data.keyvalues`)

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "keyvalues": {
          "*": { "@value": "@key" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "keyvalues": {
          "*": {
            "value": "header.@(1,key)"
          }
        }
      },
      "food": {
        "date": "header.date",
        "count": "header.count",
        "food": {
          "*": {
            "name": "foods[&1].name",
            "date": "foods[&1].date",
            "rating": "foods[&1].rating",
            "data": {
              "keyvalues": {
                "*": {
                  "value": "foods[&4].@(1,key)"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks Milo.  I can't seem to get my head around this DSL yet... will need to study this some more.